# Is "come down" or "fall down" some steps transitive?

Tags: transitivity, collocations

Who can tell me why "came down some steps" looks to me as it acts like a transitive verb?

And is "some steps" an **object** of the verb come down?

Examples:

- I came down some steps into the corridor.
- He fell down some stairs while he was...

Syntactically, what "some steps" does function in these sentences?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64108/discussion-on-question-by-bavyan-yaldo-is-come-down-or-fall-down-some-steps).

Answer (score 3):

*Some steps* is the **object** of the **preposition** *down*.

The **preposition phrase** *down some steps* acts as complement to the **intransitive verb** *came*, specifying the path followed in coming. Most verbs involving motion take such complements to specify the origin, path and goal of the motion, and these complements readily "stack", as in your example:

> I came [down some steps] [into the corridor].

You could add even more:

> I came [out the door] [down some steps] [into the corridor] [toward the hall].

It probably looks to you like a transitive verb because at some point in your learning you have been exposed to the rubbishy notion that collocations like *fall down* are "phrasal verbs"—a term which has been used, and abused, in so many different senses that it has no discernible meaning whatever.

Comment: The way you pronounce it, with "some steps/stairs" separate from "down", is not in keeping with classifying "down" as a preposition. Prepositions attach to their objects.

Comment: @Gustavson The most common object of a preposition is a noun phrase (or in some grammatical sects a determiner phrase), which may be a bare noun but may equally be a determined noun or a modified noun, or a noun which is both determined and modified. *Some steps* is a noun phrase , no different from *the steps* or *the steep steps* or *many steep steps*, and is an entirely ordinary object of a preposition.

Comment: Thank you for your best answer. You didn't just answer my question, but you answered my question and questions that may come at my mind. This the first time that i hear that not all the verbs could form phrasal verbs with their particles always act like phrasal verbs, but each parts acts alone such as this instance. @StoneyB

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you for your answer. However, I don't know if I made my point clear enough. If you were to insert a short pause in the following sentences, would you agree to do so where I wrote a slanted bar?: *I came down / some steps // I came / down the stairs.*

Comment: @Gustavson If I put a "short pause" in it would presumably be to focus some element or another; but it wouldn't alter the internal structure of the PP.